# $\mathbb E\left(W_s\int_s^tW_s\,\mathrm ds\right)$, $(W_t)$ is a brownian motion

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)$ be a Brownian motion. I found
$$\mathbb E\left(W_s\int_s^tW_s\,\mathrm ds\right)$$
in a much longer exercise, but I don't know how to compute it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E\left[W_s\int_s^tW_u\mathrm du\right]=\int_s^tE[W_sW_u]\mathrm du=\ldots$$

Comment: The formula in the question does not make sense ($s$ in $W_s$ out of the integral *and as integrand*, yikes!), this is the most resembling sound version I could think of.

Comment: sorry, I posted a clearer question here
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913414/ee-lambda-x-t-mathcalf-s-where-x-t-int-0tw-s-fracstw-t-ds
(this can also be deleted)